# What is the best way to find frequency of data receival?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, group-by

I'm trying to determine reporting period from a dataframe of reports. Options for reporting period would be:

- Monthly
- Quarterly
- Other

The dataframe looks like this:

```py
data = [['F000003Y6H', '2018-07-31'], ['F000003Y6H', '2018-08-31'], 
        ['F000003Y6H', '2018-09-30'], ['F000003Y6H', '2018-10-31'], 
        ['FOUSA06C1Y', '2021-07-31'], ['FOUSA06C1Y', '2021-10-31'], 
        ['FOUSA06C1Y', '2022-1-31'], ['FOUSA06C1Y', '2022-04-30'], 
        ['FOUSA06C1Y', '2022-7-31'], ['FO0005TYH7', '2019-5-31'], 
        ['FO0005TYH7', '2019-6-30'], ['FO0005TYH7', '2019-7-31'], 
        ['FO0005TYH7', '2019-10-31'], ['FO0005TYH7', '2020-1-31']]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['class_id', 'report_date'])
```

To determine frequency of reports(for each class_id), I have this:

```py
df['report_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['report_date'])
df['datediff_days'] = df.groupby(['class_id'])['report_date'].diff()

class_ids = df['class_id'].unique()

def determine_period(class_id):
    new_df = df.groupby('class_id')['datediff_days'].describe()
    mean_td = new_df.at[class_id, 'mean']
    mean_days = mean_td.days
    if 28<mean_days<32:
        #monthly
        #period is number of months
        period = 1
    elif 85<mean_days<95:
        #quarterly
        period = 3
    else:
        period = 0

    return period

for x in class_ids:
   period = determine_period(x)
   print("For class: " + str(x))
   print("Period is " + str(period))
```

Is there a better/simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [`pandas.DatetimeIndex.inferred_freq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.inferred_freq.html):

```py
df["report_date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["report_date"])

df["inferred_freq"] = df.groupby("class_id")["report_date"].transform(
    lambda x: pd.DatetimeIndex(x).inferred_freq
)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
      class_id report_date inferred_freq
0   F000003Y6H  2018-07-31             M
1   F000003Y6H  2018-08-31             M
2   F000003Y6H  2018-09-30             M
3   F000003Y6H  2018-10-31             M
4   FOUSA06C1Y  2021-07-31         Q-OCT
5   FOUSA06C1Y  2021-10-31         Q-OCT
6   FOUSA06C1Y  2022-01-31         Q-OCT
7   FOUSA06C1Y  2022-04-30         Q-OCT
8   FOUSA06C1Y  2022-07-31         Q-OCT
9   FO0005TYH7  2019-05-31           NaN
10  FO0005TYH7  2019-06-30           NaN
11  FO0005TYH7  2019-07-31           NaN
12  FO0005TYH7  2019-10-31           NaN
13  FO0005TYH7  2020-01-31           NaN
```